# GCM: Some devices Does not recive pushnotification in android

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am sending pushnotification to android devices from a php server,but some devices didn't get the pushnotification.

Here is the status from server

```
{"multicast_id":4893937277293136804,"success":4,"failure":10,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1452592669440333%c40440a4f9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1452592669442897%c40440a4f9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1452592669442899%c40440a4f9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1452592669442901%c40440a4f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

**PHP**

```
$key="XXXXXX";
  $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
  $fields = array(
                'registration_ids'  =>$result,
                'data'              => array( "message" =>$msg,"title"=>$title,"soundname"=>"beep.wav" ),
                );
  $headers = array(
                    'Authorization: key=' . $key,
                    'Content-Type: application/json'
                );
 try{
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
  $res = curl_exec($ch);
  print_r($res)
  }
```

From the response only 4 devices successfully get the response,but 10 failures is occurred.

Whats is the problem?

Comment: did you caheck that you have GCMregID of that 10 devices on server?

Comment: Yes ,it is in database

Comment: because your string is saying that that all devices are not registered. do one thing debug app on that device may be reg id is wrong or something elese

Comment: Please check that device token id is updated or not into database? @shammon

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34308115/what-does-mean-by-error-code-notregistered-when-sending-push-messages-using-gc?rq=1

Comment: @Rickey pattel it is updated in database

Answer (score 0):

One of these could be the problem why you are getting `NotRegistered`. See [Downstream message error response codes](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes).

> Unregistered Device    200 + error:NotRegistered
>
> An existing registration token may cease to be valid in a number of scenarios, including:
>
> - If the client app unregisters with GCM.
> - If the client app is automatically unregistered, which can happen if the user uninstalls the application. For example, on iOS, if the APNS Feedback Service reported the APNS token as invalid.
> - If the registration token expires (for example, Google might decide to refresh registration tokens, or the APNS token has expired for iOS devices).
> - If the client app is updated but the new version is not configured to receive messages.
>
> For all these cases, remove this registration token from the app server and stop using it to send messages.