# Want to know which are useless refresh tokens to remove it from text file

Tags: android, push-notification

I am using FCM. Stored refresh token in text file. Fetch that tokens from file and send push notification.

When I send notification , I got following response

> MulticastResult(multicast_id=7511693072672067374,total=3,success=2,failure=1,canonical_ids=0,results:
>   [[ errorCode=NotRegistered ], [
>   messageId=0:1488863605846176%8fe03d2ef9fd7ecd ], [
>   messageId=0:1488863605846740%8fe03d2ef9fd7ecd ]]

Now, I want to know which refresh token is get errorcode like 'NotRegistered ' to remove it from text file.
I want to send notification to almost 2000+ users

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718115/gcm-error-not-registered

Comment: Thanks, @sasikumar... I want to know how to replace the old token (Which are useless because we have reinstalled the app so new id generated) with new one.

Comment: can any one help me how to handle refresh token in above situation ?